# Configuring who to output seconds

Tags: linux, timestamp

I need to see who is logged in when. That's pretty simple using `who`, the problem is that the time output looks something like:

```
Feb 14 15:15
```

I need the seconds as well.

How can I make this happen?

I couldn't find anything relevant from Google.

Answer (score 1):

`who` does not support printing seconds. However, times are recorded accurately to `utmp` (see `man 5 utmp`.

As a workaround, you can use

```
last -F
```

to print login and logout times, including seconds. To get list of users who are logged in right now, use

```
last -F | grep "still logged in"
```

Obviously, this is not portable - if you have different locale and `last` prints that string in your local language, it's not going to work. Even uglier workaround is to use

```
last -F | grep -v '('
```

This does not depend on the English locale, but it might break in some other cases.